# HX711 - Analog Supply Regulator

Tags: microcontroller

I want to know how the analog supply regulator from the HX711 chip works. I try to search on Google and read the datasheet but I still need to figure some things.
I want to know especially what its used for, what role has the Vfb, base and Vsup pins from the module.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a run-of-the-mill "3 terminal" positive voltage regulator, EXCEPT the "series pass element" (in this case, a PNP transistor) is not integrated but must be supplied externally.

The positive (unregulated) INPUT voltage is applied to VSUP *and* the PNP's emitter.

The positive (now regulated!) OUTPUT voltage is "taken" from the PNP's collector.

The regulator itself does basically 1 thing: It "samples" the voltage applied to the "VFB" pin, compares it to some internal voltage that it generates within itself, and depending upon whether the sampled VFB voltage is "too high" or "too low", decides to draw (less) or (more) current into its "output" pin "BASE".  Basically, if VFB is too low, the chip will PULL more current into its BASE pin, turning the external PNP transistor "ON" harder, thus raising the output voltage to proper level.  Similarly, if VFB is too high, the chip will PULL *less* current into BASE, the PNP will turn "OFF" a little, and the output voltage will drop.

By choosing the resistor-divider ratio between the PNP collector (the regulated voltage output) and VFB, you can vary the output voltage to whatever value you need (within reason) so long as it's not too close to VSUP nor too low (i.e. too close to ground).

The voltage that the chip compares the VFB input voltage pin "to" is, from the datasheet, called "V_BG" (also "Reference Bypass") and is 1.25V nominal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. ..I have a curiosity: Let's say I'll use a 3.3 voltage for power,so iIhave 3.3V on the transistor emitter.That means that the voltage on the collector would be greater than the voltage on the emitter(4.3V i calculated). In this case the transistor is blocked and the analog supply regulator is useless?

Comment: If V_SUP is 3.3V then the maximum voltage on the collector would top off at about 2.8-3.0V and with poor regulation.  V_SUP must be greater than the regulated voltage you need by at least the V_CE_SAT of the transistor + a safety margin (0.2V absolute minimum).  According to datasheet, the analog supply cannot be lower than 2.6V nor higher than 5.5V, and that same range applies to V_SUP.   If the regulated supply needs to be too close to VSUP, you would have to use your own regulator circuit to supply it; the internal ckt with the external PNP would not be adequate.